# Unable to login mariadb with homebrew

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

AM not sure this is to do with me having docker and ddev installed, but I installed homebrew in my machine, and when I try to run:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I see the following error:

```
mysql: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 20 "Not a directory")
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

But if run:

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

The terminal tells me that the File already exists.

If I run brew services list, I see all the services currently running:

```
mariadb started sidney /Users/sidney/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
php     started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
redis   started sidney /Users/sidney/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

How do I manage my mysql/mariadb ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but this worked for me:

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
cp /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.default /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```